# Converting a problem into a linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider this problem : 
\begin{equation*}
\text{minimize} \hspace{.8em} |x|+|y|+|z|\\
\text{subject to} \hspace{.8em} x+y \le 1 ~~~~~~~(1)\\
\hspace{2 cm}2x+z=3~~~~~~~(2) 
\end{equation*}
This is not a linear program as the objective is not a linear function, i'm asked to construct another LP such that the solution of the above problem can be obtained from that LP.

What i think i should do is to construct 8 separate LPs as :
$$obj_1=x+y+z, \text{s.t} ~(1)+(2)+x>0,y>0,z>0 \\obj_2=-x-y-z, \text{s.t}~(1)+(2)+x<0,y<0,z<0\\obj_3=x+y-z, \text{s.t}~(1)+(2)+x>0,y>0,z<0\\...\\...$$ Total 8 separate LPs. What should be the next step ? would the solution with biggest cost will be the solution of the underlying problem ? I'm not sure about this!

Source: Linear and nonlinear programming , D.Luenberger, Y.Ye, Chapter 2, Ex 8.

Comment: Reformulation as a single LP is preferable, but if you were to solve all 8 LPs, you should take the smallest (not biggest) objective value of the 8 because you want to minimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent $x=x^+-x^-$ where $x^+, x^- \ge 0$.

At optimal value, $|x|=x^++x^-$.

We have

$$\min x^+ + x^- + y^+ + y^- + z^+ + z^-$$

subject to $$x^+ - x^- + y^+ - y^- \le 1$$

$$2(x^+ - x^-) + z^+ - z^- = 3$$

$$x^+, x^-, y^+, y^-, z^+, z^- \ge 0$$

Comment: This is quite slick , thanks .

Comment: Alternatively, you can introduce another variable, $z$. minimize it. subject to $z \ge $ those $8$ possibilities.